# Photomania- Stanford Paul Hegarty's class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

is there something wrong with core data for `xcode 4.3.2`
I'm following the `Stanford Paul Hegarty class for ios 5.0`
doing the core data walkthrough `(Video 14 Core data demo)`
I downloaded the file [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Photomania_0.zip)

I ran it in `xcode 4.3.2` but the core data doesn't seem to work because the entries in the `tableview` do not appear.
I tried to run it in another computer with `xcode 4.2` and `ios 5.0`
it's working perfectly
anybody who encountered the same problem? I'm pretty sure that `xcode` is at fault.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tag homework questions as such. Also, please take care to present your question clearly.

Comment: Please be more specific — what does "core data doesn't seem to work" mean? Error messages, screenshots, snippets of code — any info at all, really — are prerequisites to asking a question. We can't guess the setups of your computers, or your code, or what's going wrong. If you want an answer, you'll have to supply that information yourself. In addition to that, please be aware that not necessarily everyone is aware of what the Photomania sample project is — at the least, it would be nice to have a link to read up on it. :)

Comment: sorry about that. i updated my question already and i'm new here. Thanks for the tips. :)

Comment: Another comment: in Xcode 4.5 using the iPhone Simulator 5.1, Photomania also won't work!. With Simulator 5.0 and 6.0 it works. Looks like the 5.1 Simulator in Xcode 4.5 has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I am having the same problems and I am also using XCode 4.3, but just thought it was because of the Flickr license that you need and which I don't have. (In `FlickAPIKey.h`, there is a `#define FlickrAPIKey @""` and you won't download anything if you don't have that key.)

***Update***: I got myself a Flickr API key (you can just get one from their website) and tried the Photomania App on XCode 4.3: it works like a charm, so it looks like XCode is not your problem here. (Although on occasion I found that I had to stop and restart XCode to get rid of a strange bug or compiler error.) Anyway, maybe it is an idea to delete the data first before you try again: Just delete the App before you run it and the database file will get deleted as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I downloaded the IOS 5.0 simulator and it worked. I got myself an API key too. Cool. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Paul Hegarty after his class, has published an update version of his code which have a call to SAVE the CoreData database! This may be the reason why your CoreData informations doesn't persist.

His update note was:

```
// should probably saveToURL:forSaveOperation:(UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting)completionHandler: here!
// we could decide to rely on UIManagedDocument's autosaving, but explicit saving would be better
// because if we quit the app before autosave happens, then it'll come up blank next time we run
// this is what it would look like (ADDED AFTER LECTURE) ...
[document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
```

So, you have to Add the 'document saveToURL' line in the 'fetchFlickrDataInDocument' function like this:

```
- (void)fetchFlickrDataIntoDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document
    {
        dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Flickr fetcher", NULL);
        dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
            NSArray *photos = [FlickrFetcher recentGeoreferencedPhotos];
            [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{

// perform in the NSMOC's safe thread (main thread)
                for (NSDictionary *flickrInfo in photos) {
                    [Photo photoWithFlickrInfo:flickrInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];
                    // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
                }

                // should probably saveToURL:forSaveOperation:(UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting)completionHandler: here!
                // we could decide to rely on UIManagedDocument's autosaving, but explicit saving would be better
                // because if we quit the app before autosave happens, then it'll come up blank next time we run
                // this is what it would look like (ADDED AFTER LECTURE) ...
                [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
                // note that we don't do anything in the completion handler this time

            }];
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still facing the same issue using Objective-C, there is one more thing you need to do after getting API key: change all `http://` to `https://` within files in FlickrFetcher folder. This worked for me.